Sent to Safe Wallet(ETH) address that exists only for Polygon. Failed to retrieve. Searched and talked to CS but failed. Please advise
Made a transaction on ETH chain to Safewallet(Polygon) address.
Tried Safewallet intercom support and watched videos. Tried to create the address on Polygon but failed. Please advise.
Original botched transaction:https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdf60e9dae747a7b708fd4ecf0a8b6bf88a85cd4dfb4d7be3015df7b2d0b4da30
Attempt at recovery:https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe4ef40c19c896b4b57ca7fd3c26e2ad0ebafa3c819c5e1fe4612a79b813f5d7a
Multi Sig address(Polygon):
0x1945dc57c90a07840a82b69114d655DF28C9Df61
ProxyFactory address according to Safe: matic:0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2
I included HEX in the transaction as advised but failed. Please advise how I can create a ETH address in Safe. This is killing me. As anyone who can read this I'm not a very technical person.
Edit: Spoke to customer support again. Quoting his answers.
"What you have done so far is correct. The issue is that the Safe creation transaction hash that you had wasn't just for creating a Safe but also for addownerwiththreshold thus making the HEX not appropriate. You will need to wait for a response from a dev on your post and have them provide you with a new HEX which you can then paste and submit as described in the video"
"Not all users but yes our devs do frequent there. You can add the HEX details about needing the one for creation only since the one you had is both creation and addownerthreshold transaction. Then include this hash https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x533a1bd93e6dab95f3c41273431ac2eca8b3b8f111998dfd3c46c83e5c182c78 labelled as the Safe Creation Transaction"
Could any Safe Wallet devs help me out please. Any help would be appreciated.
Please point out the right address to send to and correct hex if you can.

Hey thanks for your question. The recreation transaction failed on mainnet because it was sent to the Safe Proxy Factory, while the original transaction was sent to the MultiSendCallOnly contract.
I managed to simulate a recreation transaction on Tenderly by extracting the parameters sent to the Proxy Factory from the original transaction. Can you please try sending a transaction to the address 0xa6b71e26c5e0845f74c812102ca7114b6a896ab2 with the following input data, and confirm you were able to recover your safe?
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

Thank you in advance  Best, Louis

I'M experiencing a similar issue but this time, it's for base mainnet, what do I need to do? to resolve

If it's for the same address you should be able to send the same transaction on Base as well. Could you please confirm that it worked? Thanks in advance
